# Boarding a sleeper compartment with a waiting list ticket and no reservation

Tags: trains, india, regulations, bookings, seating

What are the railway reservation rules under the below noted circumstances?

I have purchased a waiting list ticket in 3rd class A/C and did not confirm it before the journey. Can I make a valid journey and board in the 3rd AC compartment with the waiting list ticket?

Also, can I travel in Sleeper Class in a reserved compartment if I only have a general ticket without reservation? I am ready to pay the reservation cost to the [TTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTE) ([Travelling Ticket Examiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor_%28transportation%29#India)) even if no seat could be allotted by him.

Comment: Which country and which railway company are you talking about?

Comment: What is TTE and AC ?

Comment: @user3470 TTE = travelling ticket examiner = train conductor in India. ＠K.C. you should have made that clear in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Ce soir je me coucherai un peu moins con.

Comment: @user3470 Mind you, I didn't know what it meant before today (and I probably will have forgotten tomorrow). The acronym is on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTE), and the post being written in Indian English was a good hint (that, plus the insanely complicated array of classes).